# Load data from file in C

Tags: c, database

I'm creating a simple C program - employee database... My data are stored in a .txt file, separated by commas and \n, so it looks like this:

> data1,id1,name1
>
> data2,id2,name2

What is the best way (in C, not C++) to load all data from the file and every value save as independent variable (e.g. p->data, p->id, p->name)?

This is the code I use to store data into variables (not into the file, variables just for the script):

```
    void insert(emp *p,int n)
{
  p=p+n;
  printf("\nenter name of emplyee:");
  _flushall();
  gets(p->name);
  printf("\nenter employee id:");
  scanf("%d",&p->empid);
  printf("\nenter salary of the emplyee:");
  scanf("%d",&p->salary);
  printf("\nenter phone no of the emplyee:");
  flushall();
  gets(p->ph);
}
```

And this script saves data to a file:

```
void sejv(emp *p,int n)
{
      int i;
        FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("ulozka.txt","w+");
    if(fptr==NULL){
      printf("Error opening file!");   
      getchar();             
   }
  printf("Ukladani...");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   fprintf(fptr,"%d,%s,%d,%s\n",p->empid,p->name,p->salary,p->ph);   

    p=p+1;
  }

   fclose(fptr);
   exit(0);
 }
```

All I need is to load the data to the main function so I can work with it.

EDIT:
I'm adding the rest of my code:

```
typedef struct employee
{
  char name[20],ph[20];
  int empid,salary;
}emp;

void main()
{
  emp e;
  emp *p;
  int n=0,ch;
  p=&e;
}
```

And "something" from the function I need to create...

```
void nacti(emp *p,int n)
{
      int i;
        FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("ulozka.txt","r");
    if(fptr==NULL){
      printf("Error opening file!");   
      getchar();             
   }
 printf("Nacitani...");

//loading function
      p=p+n;
   fscanf(fptr,"%d,%[^\,],%d,%s", &p->empid, p->name, &p->salary,p->ph);
   printf("%s", p->name);


 }
```

I need a function that would read the data from the txt file by collumns and rows (a loop that would add the data from the first row to a p, then increase the value of p by 1, insert data from the second row and so on...)

Thank you for any advice...

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us some code of what you have tried so far so that we will know that you put some effort into researching.

Comment: You can start from your sejv (save to file) to make a "load from file" function. Just use fscanf function. There are too many examples by Googling.

Comment: If you are going to write the main in the same program, you could just call the variables directly otherwise fscanf(filepointer, "%d,%s,%d,%s",variables) will do the trick

Comment: I tried using this code:
 `for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   fscanf(fptr,"%d,%s,%d,%s\n",p->empid,p->name,p->salary,p->ph);   
  
    p=p+1;
  }`
But it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fscanf(fptr, "%d,%[^\,],%d,%s", &p->empid, p->name, &p->salary,p->ph);`

Comment: Please post additional information, espacially code, as an edit to the question, not as comment. It's more readable. As for you `fscanf`: (1) For your integers (`%d`), you must pass their address. For strings (`%s`), pass an array. So your call should probably look like `fscanf(fptr, "%d,%s\n", &p->empid, p->name)` To know for sure whether that works, we'd have to see the definition of the `emp` struct. (2) `fscanf` returns a value, namely the nzmber of converted items. Use it.

Comment: OK, I added more information to the post...

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code it can be done ad shown below:

```
struct data
{
    int index;
    int id;
    char name[30];
};

int main ()
{
    struct data p[3];
    int i=0;
FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt","r+");
while(fscanf(fp,"%d,%d,%s",&p[i].index,&p[i].id,p[i].name) != EOF)
{
    i++;
}
i=0;
while(i<3)
{
fprintf(fp,"%d %d %s\n",p[i].index,p[i].id,p[i].name);
i++;
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: But this code will only read the first line of a file, won't it?

Comment: And is there any way that I could apply it to my existing script, that it would save loaded data into my variables p->something?